# RStudio gives "Incorrect function" when setting git as Version control

Tags: r, git, rstudio

When I create a new project and select to create a new Git repository, or when I try to change the version control system in project options I receive a RStudio error stating "Incorrect function" with a big X and no extra information.

The below link has a similar issue, but their solution of changing the path for git.exe has not helped (i have tried all three paths)

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200632528-Git-Error-Incorrect-Function

Some extra notes:

- RStudio allows me to clone repository to set new working directory
- Also git works in bash, so i feel this is an RStudio issue.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I encountered the same error. For me it also had to do with using a network path not a local directory for the project location (as for lewis1211).

Workaround: Map the network drive. E.g. Map your //server/share to some drive, say Z: (using map network drive, if you are using windows). If you set your project up under Z: then, it works.

Comment: The answer for many problems, it appears, is to map the network drive

Comment: worked for me as well. My project was on a network path and git locally. Moved the project locally and it works fine now.

Comment: I didn't need to move the project. Just close it, and then reopen it using the "Open Project" dialogue, navigating to it using the driver letters rather than the network path. Then git worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already chosen `"git.exe"` in `RStudio --> Tools --> Global Options --> Git/SVN`, then try to open Rstudio shell and type `git init`. In my case it showed "Permission denied", and after running as administrator the problem has gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer if it fixes your problem: I reproduced this when trying to use a network path for a project location. When using a local directory no error occurs.  Could indeed be an RStudio issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run you R studio as Project administration. 
This solves my issue.

Comment: What do you mean run as project administration? Run as admin?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
I had the same problem. The **Git-RStudio-Connection** fails but git is working perfectly in the CMD. When running the `git init` command in CMD it works and creates a `.git` folder. But running the `git init` command in the RStudio terminal fails with a message `Warning: unable to access 'C:/Users/%username%/.gitconfig': Permission denied` ... `fatal: unknown error occured while reading the configuration files`.

The **Version Control Sytem (VCS)** or git-Panel does not appear in RStudio and selecting it in the projects options leads to the same message `Error: Unzulässige Function` (eng. `Error: Incorrect function`).

A closer look into the `.gitconfig` file should give you a new solution approach hopefully without having administration rights. Comparing the installation on the integration worksation with a productive workstation shows, that on the Test-Machine an **incomplete .gitconfig** file is on `C:/Users/%username%/.gitconfig` and on the Productive-Machine a complete gitconfig file is on `Z:/.gitconfig`. By the way, Z is a mapped drive which is linking to the company's user-profile settings (see `CMD > echo %HOMEDRIVE%`).

According to this analysis there should be multiple possible solution approaches:
(1) **delete** the corrupt `.gitconfig` and hope the the system is correctly looking into your profiles directory
(2) **complete** the `.gitconfig` file that all necessary information are there. The message `fatal: unknown error occured while reading the configuration files` could actually be a hint, that the first message `access... permission denied` is false and the problem lies in the incomplete file.
(3) Be aware that there can be a **confusion between ".gitconfig" as FILE and ".gitconfig" as FOLDER**. Check this with changing directory with `cd` to folder and `cat` to show the file content. It will tell you that you cannot display a folder as file-content.
(4) Change the location of the config file with **git config --file FullnameToGitconfig**. e.g. `git config --file %USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig` or `git config --file %USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig/gitconfig` or `git config --file %HOMEDRIVE%/.gitconfig` etc.

```
[user]
    name = DOE John 
    email = john.doe@acme.com
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[diff]
    guitool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/GitExtensions/GitExtensions.exe\" fileeditor
```

Comment: SOLVED! Translated from French from working colleague: "Thank you for the solution. I actually had the same problem and stackoverflow's solution (1) (delete the folder C:/Users/%username%/.gitconfig ) solved the problem. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer :)"

Comment: Check your configuration with `git config --list --show-origin` in the end.

Comment: (3) SOLVED it! Working colleague: Das `FILE ".gitconfig"` sichern. Den `FOLDER ".gitconfig"` löschen und mit dem `FILE ".gitconfig"` ersetzen.